# Правильный синтаксис для дочернего атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как наиболее правильно решить след. вопрос.
Есть динамические поля в таблице( добавляем кликом). Можно ли, ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ элемент tr c id="**addr(N)**" >1  то у элемента tr c id='**addr(N-1)**" изменить атрибуты id у его td ("number" и "val")

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
                        var i=1;
                        $("#add_row").click(function(){b=i-1;
                            $('#addr'+i).html($('#addr'+b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i+1);
                            $('#tab').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
                            i++;
                        });
                        $("#delete_row").click(function(){
                            if(i>1){
                                $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
                                i--;
                            }
                            calc();
                        });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab" style="border:2">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="addr1">
      <td id="number">1</td>
      <td id="val">Value1-2</td>
    </tr>
 
  </tbody>
  <div>
  <button id="add_row" class="pull-left btn btn-info btn-mini " style="margin-left: 5%">Добавить строку</button>
 <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-mini">Удалить строку</button>
  </div>
   
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Разметка:

```
<table id="tab" style="border:2">
    <tr class='empty'>
        <td>
            <input class='name'>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input class='barcode'></td>
        <td>
            <input class='artikul'>
        </td>
        <td>
             <input class='artikul_original'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

В разметке убрал id, если они реально нужны, можете добавлять их в коде с инкрементом цифры.

Код:

```
var name, barcode, artikul, artikul_original;
    //парсим json, чтобы получить значение для внесения в каждый инпут, раскидываем значения по переменным
//далее присваиваем инпутам значения переменных
    $('.empty').children().children('.name').val(name); 
    $('.empty').children().children('.barcode').val(barcode); 
    $('.empty').children().children('.artikul').val(artikul); 
    $('.empty').children().children('.artikul_original').val(artikul_original); 
    $('.empty').removeClass('empty'); // убираем у текущей строки класс пустой
    $('#tab').append(' <tr class="empty"> <td> <input class="name"> </td> <td>  <input class="barcode"> </td> <td>  <input class="artikul"> </td> <td>  <input class="artikul_original"> </td> </tr>'); // добавляем новую строку с классом empty, чтобы в следующей итерации к ней обратиться
```

Код идет к строке с классом empty, проваливается на 2 уровня к потомкам (инпутам) и заполняет каждый в соответствии с классом. Потом убивает у строки класс empty, чтобы следующая итерация не затронула эту строку.
Затем создает новую пустую строку с целевым классом.
Если я вас понял правильно, это решает задачу) Если нужна помощь в добавлении id, то пишите, дополню

Comment: Стоит замечать, что двух одинаковых id на странице быть не должно?) -  это и пытаюсь избежать

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Пытаюсь разобрать. В логе ругается на var n=Number($(this).attr('id').replace('addr',''))+1  -- Cannot read property 'replace'. Пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: можете разбить 
var n=$(this).attr('id');
console.log(n);
n= n.replace('addr','');
console.log(n);
В консоли должны выпасть два значения n подряд

Comment: Не хотите на этапе генерации новой строки сразу генерить новые id у добавляемых td?

Comment: Не хотите на этапе генерации новой строки сразу генерить новые id у добавляемых td? - Да,так и пытаюсь. Потом мне их нужно заполнять по этому ж id из json. Представляю так - у последней строки (заполняемой) id не изменяется, у всех предыдущих - +1.

Comment: Или я неверно добавляю эту функцию в функцию генера новой строки

Comment: Undefinded.   в функции все tr. Но есть tr без id.

Comment: А какая целевая задача? Сейчас ваш код добавляет строки без столбцов, так и должно быть?

Comment: Думал сократить код для вопроса  - а с итогом напросился на ошибку. В эти строках есть инпуты. И id  меняем у них, а в  инпут вносятся данные из модального окна с json после поиска по этому id. Вот и хотелось, чтобы не менялся id последний, а все остальные менялись на новые - тогда не нужно переписывать код в модальном окне.

Comment: реализация в формате "менять все предыдущие id" -это самый костыльный из возможных костылей)
Можете описать алгоритм поэтапно?
Я пока понял так:
1. Есть таблица с 1 строкой и двумя инпутами в ней
2. жмем кнопку "добавить строку" - > добавляется строка с пустыми инпутами, в предыдущие инпуты калькулируется какое-то значение.
Где в этом процессе модальное окно? откуда берется json и куда вносится?

Comment: Про костыли понял!)) Есть пустая строка в таблице, много столбцов с инпутами и кнопка подобрать. От кнопки уходим в модальное окно с окном поиск. Поиск в модальном окне из БД с json. После поиска необходимого  - кнопка добавить и эта строка ( она   в модальном в виде строки таблицы) переносится в таблицу в строку с инпутами в соответствующие столбцы (name, barcode, artikul, artikul-original, ед.измерен., модель) . И потом если необходимо - добавить строку. Но в основном всегда необходимо.

Comment: Поменял в ответе, посмотрите

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Прикрутил. Работает. В общем так и думал, что по заполнению строки добавляется новая, но c jQuery на вы. Нужно теперь собрать автонумерацию на этот код и удаление строки. Верно я понимаю, что строку можно идентифицировать фактически по любому атрибуту - например data-number="numberN"?

Comment: Если кнопка удаления в строке, то удалять строку можно обратившись к родителю кнопки. 
т.е. если кнопка внутри одного из td, то код по нажатию на кнопку будет таким:
$('.класс кнопки').click(function(){$(this).parent().parent().remove();});
Еще можно перебрать все строки и найти ту, в которой какой-то атрибут равен заданному вами и эту строку удалить.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки! так вроде все понимаю. Включил в td кнопку - но она удаляет все строки кроме первой и удаляет в первой внесенные значения.

Comment: И ощущение, что эта кнопка взяла на себя submit